# Need the decoded data while from server esp32 send and Receiving in react native cli

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32, react-native-ble-plx

"How can I ensure that the decoded data I receive on my mobile matches the data shown on the ESP32 console when connecting the ESP32 to my mobile?"

My server side code is ESP32-C++

My Client side code is React Native-Cli